# Proof By Induction for function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am an undergrad Computer Engineering Student that is struggling through a class in discrete mathematics. One question in particular from a recent assignment has me stumped. Assuming that $T$ is a total non decreasing function that maps from Z+ to R+, also that $k \in Z^{+}$, and $T(2^{k}) = T(2^{k-1})+5$, and that $T(1)=7$ prove by induction that

$T(2^k) = 5k + 7$

I am confused about where to begin this. I would take my base case as k=0 from the expression im asked to prove, but then what is the inductive hypothesis and where would i go from there for the inductive step?
I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how induction proofs look like in general? If so, then I suggest you attempt to repeat their process, and show your result here (at least one or two steps).

Comment: Are you also given that $T(1) = 7$?

Comment: Generally yes I know how they work but im having trouble getting started on that one. What do i use for base case, top expression or the one proved. further what do i begin with for inductive hypothesis?

Comment: Yes copper hat we are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $k=0$ is ok by the hypothesis $T(1)=7$, since $
2^0=1$. Then suppose for $k> 0$ that the relation is true. Calculate $T(2^{k+1})=T(2^k)+5= 5k+ 7 +5$ by inductive hypothesis; finally you have only to rearrange the right part writing $5k +7 +5= 5(k+1) +7$.

Comment: why is $T(2^{k+1})=T(2^k)+5$ true?

Comment: This is of course the inductive step! Once you verified the basic step, here $k=0$, you suppose the formula you have to prove is true for a generic $k> 0$ and verify it is true also for k+1 exploiting the previous assumption. Doubts about the  proofs by induction?

Comment: Very very many doubts about proof by induction yes

Comment: I think I now understand this example, kind of lol

Comment: Well, anyway revise the theory, proof by induction are everywhere in Math! You'll see there is nothing difficult and it is a powerful tool.

Comment: in your scenario, what is the inductive hypothesis? I apologize for being so confused :(

Comment: Exactly your first comment to my answer!

Comment: It is what you assume after the basic step, i.e. the formula you have to prove for a generic k.

Comment: This kind of proof works this way: if I suppose, after verifying a concrete case i.e. the basic step, that my formula is true for a generic k,  is it true also for k+1? The validity of the proof follows by the fact we took a  generic k.

Answer (score 1):

Step one:
Find all elements up to k-1
By assuming T(2^k-1) = 5(k - 1) + 7
Step two:
Then add the kth term (2^k) to a closed form of the above equation, 5(k - 1) + 7

If the equations are the same you have proved by induction.

Base case as described in question for completeness of answer:
T(1) = 7
T(2^(0)) = 5(0) + 7
T(1) = 7

Comment: Remember to include the base case, otherwise induction does not work!

Comment: His question regarded only the inductive hypothesis and the inductive step since OP seemed to have the base case

Comment: But to help avoid confusion (especially by future users) it is probably useful to include a mention of it. Also, you may want to use the MathJax formatting for your answer. Welcome to the site, by the way!

Comment: What would be the inductive hypothesis in this case? Thanks for the welcome

Comment: The equation following the word "assuming" @pingOfDoom

Comment: I assume from base case to the k-1 term it works. If I add the kth term to the equation I should be right back to where I started with T(2^k) = 5k +7, if it works. If I go T(2^k) = 5(k-1) + 7 + (2^k), does this help you visualize what they are asking?

Comment: @pingOfDoom is this any clearer?